# What is the total resistance of circuit with transistor and 10K (for example) resistor (+pic)?

Tags: transistors, resistors, resistance

Should it be more or less than 10K and why? I doubt that it can be less than 10К, because such current (voltage/10K) should go through base-emitter at least, and all other current should go via collector-emitter junction.
[image: transistorplusresistor]

Comment: But you just said yourself there is a current via 10k, and  more current will flow via collector, so what does that tell you, is it less or more load than 10k? Why not just simulate it to see the result?

Comment: You're missing a key concept.  Just because this circuit is not pure resistance, from the outside it can LOOK like a resistance.  There will be a voltage, and there will be a current.  From ohms law (V=IR), there will be a resistance you can calculate.    HInt:  Since you know "I" will go up, if "V" stays constant... what happens to "R"???

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is non-linear and does not have a well-defined single number for "total resistance"; it will behave differently depending on whether the transistor remains in cutoff, or enters forward active mode. However, it's clear that its effective "resistance" can be far less than 10k, with the following proof by (counter)example.

Suppose that the voltage on the terminals is 1.0 V, and assume that Vbe is approximately 0.7 V in this configuration. The drop across the resistor is 300 mV, hence 30 uA flows to the base. If the hFE of the transistor is 100 (a reasonable assumption) then the collector current is 3 mA. 1.0 V / 3 mA is approximately 300 ohms.

You can differentiate all terms in the above derivation to convince yourself that the *small-signal* impedance around this operating point is also on the order of approx. 300 ohms.

On the other hand, for a voltage of 0.1 V, the resistance is indeed very large. The B-E junction of the transistor is reverse-biased, and no current aside from leakage can flow.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the voltage it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If the voltage is less than a few hundred mV the effective "resistance" is far more than 10K.

If the voltage is greater than half a volt or so, it will be less, assuming the transistor has an hFE >> 1.

From a simulation:

[image]

The crossover in this simulation is at about 563mV. At higher voltages (above a few volts) it appears more like a 50-65\$\Omega\$ resistance. Self-heating is not simulated here. At 100mV it appears more like a ~50G\$\Omega\$ resistor.